# Using different historical data from different brokers during backtesting

Tags: historical-data, backtesting, tick-data

Since different brokers and data providers might apply their own additional offsets to the spreads of the same instruments, what are some concerns that might rise if we merge their data to create a longer historical data to backtest on.

i.e concatenating tick data of one period from data provider 1 to the tick data from data provider 2 for the missing periods in data provider 2.

Comment: What are *additional offsets to the spreads of the same instruments*?